# How not to store MAC addresses but still keep the knowledge about how it moves across the city?

Tags: algorithm, architecture, cryptography, blockchain

I heard that there are companies that can [track people's WiFi-enabled devices](https://www.crc.id.au/tracking-people-via-wifi-even-when-not-connected/) (smartphones, laptops, tablets) by collecting MAC addresses from their probe requests.

So, let's say that I have a distributed network of access points which gather those probe requests (I'm asking just out of curiosity). There are many privacy concerns about the idea. What can I do to have statistical knowledge about people moving from point to point but without storing their MAC addresses?

I thought that I could hash that MAC addresses using hash functions, so I wouldn't have MACs and I would still be able to track devices by comparing hashes. But that's not enough. I think that maybe there's something more that I can do.

Ideally, I could have just IDs of devices (but not MACs, my own IDs). Is there a way to accomplish that?

Perhaps the access points would have to talk with each other and somehow magically agree that this MAC is the same MAC as previously and send to the server the ID which is assigned to this MAC by combining data from some (all?) access points. That way it would be harder to get the MACs.

Answer (score 1):

I think a hash is exactly what you want here, why would it not be enough? If you hash the MAC with an algorithm like HMACSHA256 and just store the resulting hash, even if someone where to get hold of your database AND your secret key they wouldn't be able to work out what the MAC addresses were, unless they also had those MAC addresses which they could then hash with your secret key and compare to the ones in your database to see if there was a a match.